# Chrome sync settings under Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

I checked many forums but not found answer that I require. What I want is to block for users option to log to browser and sync bookmarks, password and stuff to their google account.

Is there a way to permanently hide either log in option in Options or Options it self in Chrome under Ubuntu.

I am not interested how to hide only the log on question that popups at the beginning.

Thanks for Help

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to hide the "Sign into Chrome" option in the Chrome menu? That won't be possible as it's baked into the Chrome source code and cannot be overwritten.